# replace option text with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following html:

```
<select class="select menuifilter" name="ifilter">
   <option selected="selected" value="0">All</option>
   <option value="1">Single user option</option>
   <option value="7">Group user options</option>
</select>
```

I want to replace the option text "Group" with "Multi" using jQuery.

My code looks liks this:

```
$('select option').text( $("select option").text().replace("Group", "Multi") );
```

But that code doesnt work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
$('.menuifilter option:contains("Group")').text(function(idx, text){
    return text.replace('Group', 'Multi')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/x9Usn/)

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
 $('select option:contains("New")').text('temp');
    $('select option:contains("Old")').text('New');
    $('select option:contains("temp")').text('old');
```